# If language L is decidable show that $L^R$ is also decidable.

Tags: computability, turing-machines

If L is decidable, then the language $L^R$ = {$w^R$|w ∈ L} of the reversals of all strings in L is decidable too.

My approach to this was to define M' as a decider for $L^R$ such that it was a modified version of M. M' would reverse all transitions of M such that the direction is the reverse (by swapping the defined states in the transition around) and swap the initial state with the halting state ha around

Would this not be a solution that shows that $L^R$ is also decidable?

I know the alternative is to construct a compiler that takes input $w^R$ and reverses it to $w$. Feed w$ in to M and if M accepts then M' accepts etc.

Comment: Your idea needs a LOT more detail, if it works at all (I'm fairly convinced this construction can't work, but I have no proof). Intuitively, your construction of reversing arrows in $M$ corresponds to running the _computation_ backwards. NOT to reversing the string.

Comment: But running the computation backwards would compute its reversal, therefore accept strings that are are the reversal of strings in L, and when you point out 'Not to reversing the string' there is no need to reverse the string I thought... I understand that it is very vague and my idea is highly unlikely to work but just looking to clarify my understanding.

Comment: Computing "2+3 --> 5" backwards turns 5 into 2+3. It does NOT compute 3+2 --> 5. This isn't a perfect analogy, but it illustrates the issue with your idea

Comment: Ok, I kind of get what you are saying now. The example is more related to the function computed by a Turing Machine.... I'll put some more though into it and thanks for the response

Comment: Is about decidable languages or regular languages? If it's decidable languages then the solution is much more simple then what you're thinking about, you don't really need to modify the direction of anything in the state machine, just add some pre-processing.

Comment: Reversing the state machine would work also, your idea is mostly right but you need to add more details (such as considering which direction the tape head moves). Here's an added hint: your reversed state machine can be non-deterministic, even if the original state machine was deterministic.

Comment: Doing it that way will be more of a hassle though, there's just much more room for error. Note that the last tape square read in the computation might not actually be the last square in the input. Note also that by the end of the computation there may be more data added beyond the initial input, or the initial input will have been modified. How would you properly read those squares? How would you know what to write at each step? There are ways to get around this but it's a huge pain in the ass. Reversing the state machine should be reserved for regular languages.